# Induction on proofs in infinitary logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In propositional infinitary logic over countable conjunctions, you may provide proofs of countable length. My question is how you may perform induction on proofs then and is there a last element of the proof and if so how is it determined.

Comment: Typically, a proof/derivation in these systems is a particular kind of tree. We then use a form of induction on trees: we prove that each leaf node has a property, and that if all children of a node have a property then so does the parent. This implies that the root of the tree has the property - the root serves as the "last" stage of the proof in these systems.

Comment: Note that the induction Carl describes only applies to **well-founded** trees, that is trees with no infinite paths. *(Indeed, "induction along" a given tree is equivalent to the given tree being well-founded (assuming choice) in exactly the same way that induction along a linear ordering is equivalent to that linear ordering being a well-ordering (assuming choice)).* Infinitary proofs do correspond to well-founded trees.

Answer (score 0):

With induction there does not need to be a last element ... think of standard forms of mathematical induction where we show things to be trus for all (i.e. Infinitely many!) natural numbers.  There does need to be a 'next' element though, but all that is fine for infinitary logics where we have infinite but still countable length proofs. So, induction works perfectly for infinitary logics.

Comment: To cite from "Languages with expressions of infinite length" by Karp which sparked my question: "A formula A is provable iff there is a sequence of fewer than $\omega_1$ formulas, the last of which is A, s.t. each formulas is either an axiom, or obtained from the before by a rule of inference." I'm unsure, since there doesn't need to be a last formula, how to determine what a derivation actually proves.